# appengine unnamed files in blob viewer

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm creating files using the appengine files service. Those files don't have a filename. They show up as "(unnamed)" in the Blob Viewer. Is there a way to set a name so I can easily keep track of my files?

```
filename = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='text/plain')
with files.open(filename, 'a') as f:
    f.write("Foo\n")
files.finalize(filename)
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can set the `_blobinfo_uploaded_filename` like this:

```
filename = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='text/plain', _blobinfo_uploaded_filename='filename.txt')
```